# Align multiple equations with multiple expressions

Tags: equations, pdftex, align

Here what I have done so far. I want the middle space to reduce a bit.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
\Vert\mathbf{R}\Vert_F^2  & \le  \Vert\mathbf{R}\Vert_F^2 +\lambda\Vert 
\mathbf{B}^{'}\Vert_F^2-\sum_{k=1}^{m}\Vert \mathbf{B}^{'}\mathbf{A}\Vert_F^2 & & = 
\Vert\mathbf{R}\Vert_F^2 +\lambda\Vert \mathbf{B}^{'}\Vert_F^2-\sum_{k=1}^{m}\Vert
\mathbf{b}_k\mathbf{a}_{[k]}\Vert_F^2 \nonumber \\
& = \Vert\mathbf{R}\Vert_F^2 +\lambda\sum_{k=1}^{m}\Vert \mathbf{b}_k\Vert_2^2 -
\sum_{k=1}^{m}\Vert \mathbf{W}_k\Vert_F^2 & &= \Vert\mathbf{R}\Vert_F^2 -
\sum_{k=1}^{m}\Vert    \mathbf{b}_k\Vert_2^2\Vert\mathbf{a}_{[k]}\Vert_2^2 +\lambda m 
\label{eq6} 
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What does `^{'}` signify? It it signifies the transpose operation, it should probably be written as `'`, i.e., *not* raised and made smaller by the `^{...}` "wrapper".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add some negative space, for example `\hspace*{-1em}` before the last `=`

MWE

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
\Vert\mathbf{R}\Vert_F^2  & \le  \Vert\mathbf{R}\Vert_F^2 +\lambda\Vert
\mathbf{B}^{'}\Vert_F^2-\sum_{k=1}^{m}\Vert \mathbf{B}^{'}\mathbf{A}\Vert_F^2 & \hspace*{-1em} & =
\Vert\mathbf{R}\Vert_F^2 +\lambda\Vert \mathbf{B}^{'}\Vert_F^2-\sum_{k=1}^{m}\Vert
\mathbf{b}_k\mathbf{a}_{[k]}\Vert_F^2 \nonumber \\
& = \Vert\mathbf{R}\Vert_F^2 +\lambda\sum_{k=1}^{m}\Vert \mathbf{b}_k\Vert_2^2 -
\sum_{k=1}^{m}\Vert \mathbf{W}_k\Vert_F^2 & \hspace*{-1em} &= \Vert\mathbf{R}\Vert_F^2 -
\sum_{k=1}^{m}\Vert    \mathbf{b}_k\Vert_2^2\Vert\mathbf{a}_{[k]}\Vert_2^2 +\lambda m
\label{eq6}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

Anyway, as you can see, the equation is still too long to fit in the lines. I'd suggest to insert some more breaks:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\Vert\mathbf{R}\Vert_F^2  & \le  \Vert\mathbf{R}\Vert_F^2 +\lambda\Vert
\mathbf{B}^{'}\Vert_F^2-\sum_{k=1}^{m}\Vert \mathbf{B}^{'}\mathbf{A}\Vert_F^2 \\
& = \Vert\mathbf{R}\Vert_F^2 +\lambda\Vert \mathbf{B}^{'}\Vert_F^2-\sum_{k=1}^{m}\Vert
\mathbf{b}_k\mathbf{a}_{[k]}\Vert_F^2 \\
& = \Vert\mathbf{R}\Vert_F^2 +\lambda\sum_{k=1}^{m}\Vert \mathbf{b}_k\Vert_2^2 -
\sum_{k=1}^{m}\Vert \mathbf{W}_k\Vert_F^2 \\
& = \Vert\mathbf{R}\Vert_F^2 -\sum_{k=1}^{m}\Vert
\mathbf{b}_k\Vert_2^2\Vert\mathbf{a}_{[k]}\Vert_2^2 +\lambda m
\label{eq6}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

Notice the use of `equation` and `aligned` instead of `align` to avoid using `\nonumber`.

Comment: @VinayakAbrol you're welcome

Comment: An `aligned` environment with a single alignment point is equivalent to the `split` environment. Using `\lVert` and `\rVert`, as needed, instead of the plain `\Vert` might produce better spacing in some cases. It certainly makes the code easier to read and debug...

Answer (score 3):

Here is how I would do it:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[margin = 4cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\newcommand*\Vector[1]{\mathbf{#1}}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\norm}{\lVert}{\rVert}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\something}{\lbrack}{\rbrack}

\begin{document}

\noindent Either
\begin{alignat}{2}
  \norm{\Vector{R}}_{F}^{2}
  &\le \norm{\Vector{R}}_{F}^{2} + \lambda \norm{\Vector{B}'}_{F}^{2}
       -\sum_{k = 1}^{m} \norm{\Vector{B}'{\mkern -2mu}\Vector{A}}_{F}^{2}
  &&= \norm{\Vector{R}}_{F}^{2} + \lambda \norm{\Vector{B}'}_{F}^{2}
      -\sum_{k = 1}^{m} \norm{\Vector{b}_{k}\Vector{a}_{\something{k}}}_{F}^{2} \nonumber \\
  &= \norm{\Vector{R}}_{F}^{2} + \lambda \sum_{k = 1}^{m} \norm{\Vector{b}_{k}}_{2}^{2}
     -\sum_{k = 1}^{m} \norm{\Vector{W}_{k}}_{F}^{2}
  &&= \norm{\Vector{R}}_{F}^{2} - \sum_{k = 1}^{m} \norm{\Vector{b}_{k}}_{2}^{2}
      \,\norm{\Vector{a}_{\something{k}}}_{2}^{2} + \lambda m 
\end{alignat}
or
\begin{align}
  \norm{\Vector{R}}_{F}^{2}
  &\le \norm{\Vector{R}}_{F}^{2} + \lambda \norm{\Vector{B}'}_{F}^{2}
       -\sum_{k = 1}^{m} \norm{\Vector{B}'{\mkern -2mu}\Vector{A}}_{F}^{2} \nonumber \\
  &= \norm{\Vector{R}}_{F}^{2} + \lambda \norm{\Vector{B}'}_{F}^{2}
     -\sum_{k = 1}^{m} \norm{\Vector{b}_{k}\Vector{a}_{\something{k}}}_{F}^{2} \nonumber \\
  &= \norm{\Vector{R}}_{F}^{2} + \lambda \sum_{k = 1}^{m} \norm{\Vector{b}_{k}}_{2}^{2}
     -\sum_{k = 1}^{m} \norm{\Vector{W}_{k}}_{F}^{2} \nonumber \\
  &= \norm{\Vector{R}}_{F}^{2} - \sum_{k = 1}^{m} \norm{\Vector{b}_{k}}_{2}^{2}
     \,\norm{\Vector{a}_{\something{k}}}_{2}^{2} + \lambda m 
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Notice the use of `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` from the [`mathtools`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathtools) package.

Comment: In the pursuit of perfection, I'd be tempted to add `\,` (thinspace) between the two adjacent norm expressions in the final row. I'd also replace all instances of `^{'}` with `'`, *or* I'd write `^{\prime}`.

Comment: following Mico in pursuit of perfection, i'd be tempted to make all the delimiters uniform in size -- the sub/sup on the version with `\Vector{B}^{\prime}` look more nicely spaced than those on the shorter ones.  however, i agree with karlkoeller that `aligned` is preferable to `align` and lots of `\nonumber`s

Comment: @Mico The `\,` is already used. `:)` I've now implemented `^{\prime}`.

Comment: @barbarabeeton `^{\prime}` inplemented. The `align` is because I _guess_ the reference is only to the last expression.

Comment: @SvendTveskæg Using `'` is easier than `^{\prime}` and completely equivalent; also `''` is equivalent to `^{\prime\prime}` and so on. Instead `^{'}` is wrong.